# Showing author box on post page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i am just a beginner in word-press as well in PHP.I am trying to display author information along with his picture in the post and have successfully able to fetch all the data from gravatar.com and able to display it on the right hand side bar successfully.

Currently this box is coming through out the website, but my requirement is that it should only be displayed when reader is on the post detail page.
As per my little knowledge of word-press, i kw that each post will going to relate to some category.
How can i able to show the author box to only post detail page and hide it from all other places.Any help in this regard will be much helpful

just to edit i have added following code

```
<?php  $category_ids = remove_element(get_all_category_ids(),'274');
     if (in_category($category_ids)) { ?>
```

this code is not working but if i pass a single category id to `in_category()` function like

```
 <?php  
     if (in_category('8')) { ?>
```

if block is working fine.

Comment: what is the code for remove_element, is it returning the array ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit sidebar.php and use the [is_single conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single) to make the code show up only if a single post is displayed.

Wrap your code in

```
<?php  if(is_single()){
// your code goes here! 
}?>
```

Comment: I already have single.php file under my theme and i am trying to show the author info box on sidebar.php

Comment: Ah sorry about that I read your question too fast, I'll modify my answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show something on the post detail page. You've to mess with single.php, it is the main source. However if you want to show some text from right sidebar only on Post Pages you can do this.

```
if(is_single()){
// do this when viewing single post details
}
```